# How do I find out what driver is being used with a webcam in linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, webcam

On my Ubuntu (10.04) system, the Ativa SMP-6AS webcam has worked out of the box. On a minimalistic (no gui) Debian Lenny system, it only creates devices for audio (/dev/audio1, /dev/dsp1, /dev/mixer1), but no corresponding /dev/video0 (like it does on Ubuntu). How do I find out what driver it's using on the Ubuntu system so I can install it on the Debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ ls -ld /sys/class/video4linux/video0/device/driver
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 2010-07-16 07:35 /sys/class/video4linux/video0/device/driver -> ../../../../../../bus/usb/drivers/uvcvideo
```

So, `video0` is `uvcvideo`.

Comment: I see...it's the same driver here. How would I install this? The debian system runs 2.6.32 and the uvc webpage says that it is installed by default in kernels later than 2.6.26. I don't seem to have it anywhere on my system...

Comment: For that part you'll have to talk to someone that knows Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, in /var/log/dmesg, look for string video. Mine is:

```
# cat /var/log/dmesg |grep video
[    0.604968] pci 0000:01:05.0: Boot video device
[   21.219308] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   21.230220] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Chicony USB 2.0 Camera (04f2:b19a)
[   21.244239] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Output line 3 say it's uvcvideo driver, with a little more details on the camera itself.

Comment: Of course, this will fail if the camera happens to use some other driver, e.g. `zr364xx`.

Comment: If using other drivers, it's likely to show in dmesg output too. They all use printk().